# Binding an argument to a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code snippet below. When I hit the URL, I get the value of the id passed to the route on the console but I cannot explain why. Can someone tell me how the id was passed into the autoIndexUser function?

```js
const { autoIndexUser } = require("../utils/index_user");

router.patch("/update/:_id", auth, async (req, res) => {
    const { _id } = req.params;
  
    const user = await User.findById(_id);
    ...
    updateIndex(_id, "people", autoIndexUser);
  
    return res.status(200).send({ newUser });
  });
```

Here is index_user.js file:

```js
async function autoIndexUser(id) {
    ...
    console.log(id)
}
```

It would be understandable for me if the function was called by passing the "id" inside but it wasn't.

```js
// Updates the index
async function updateIndex(id, index, index_data) {
  // Checks if the index exiss
  const isDeleted = deleteIndex(id, index);
  if (isDeleted) {
    index_data(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: what does updateIndex do?

Comment: Since we don't know what the `updateIndex` function does with `autoIndexUser`: No.

Comment: @Quentin I have edited the question to include the updateIndex function